# Personalized Gallery what are my options?

Tags: customization, images, users, uploads, gallery

In my game website I would like to implement a Screenshot page where my registered users can upload images to it (it might be more then 1 screenshot page, 1 for the users and 1 for the game in question what I mean is users can upload and the staff will be using the game website available images so it would be 2 different categories or w/e).

Once an image is uploaded it will be pending for approval before becoming available on the gallery page.

I would like that the page that will display the list of images will be displaying it as thumbnail or resized images to a smaller size and the bigger image will show uppon click or something alike.

**What i would like to know is:**

- Is there a plugin with such features
  ?
- What are my options here ?

---

I've got a good programming background, if i were to make such changes what would be my best approch to it ? like creating a custom template page or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this plugin that entirelly fits my needs while I modificating the NextGen so I tought I should post it here in case some one was looking for something like this:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-public-uploader/screenshots/

With this I can simple set the minimun access to subscribers and add a tag to a page and it will allow registered users to upload images to a pre-selected gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know offhand if there's a plugin already to do this, but if you were to go about programming it yourself, here's some pointers to get you started:

Media file upload is pretty simple... You can take advantage of a lot of the well-documented and commented functions defined for the admin media manager in `wp-admin/includes/image.php`, `wp-admin/includes/file.php`, and `wp-admin/includes/media.php`. I wrote a rough tutotial on how to implement this: http://goldenapplesdesign.com/2010/07/03/front-end-file-uploads-in-wordpress/

You can predefine the sizes you want using `add_image_size()` calls in your functions.php file. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size for add_image_size reference and http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/ for a great tutorial on using post thumbnail images.

There are lots of possible ways to structure your data, but the way to use the most of WP's API features is to have your users screenshots defined as a custom post type with a featured image attached to it, which is set as a draft when uploaded, and updated to published on approval.

You would need one custom page template to handle the file upload, and one to display the screenshots, and a couple helper functions to register the post type and enable the UI on the admin side to manage the uploads.

Comment: thaks for your response, I have started editing NextGen with subscriber upload support on multisite feature and will see where this leads me... So far it is going ok while a lot more complicated then your example which seems very easy to approch, thank you.